# What is the form collection in asp.net/html?

Tags: asp.net, html, http, request.servervariables

Simple question but one i need to clarify for myself. In terms of collections that can be accessed in the request object there is:

```
Cookies:    (whats in  a text file in the browser)
Querystring:   (whats passed in the url like [key=value&key=value etc])
Server Variables:  ?
Form Variables:    ?
```

The ones with the ? next to are the ones that I dont really understand where in the http packet/html they are placed. I did a capture using wireshark:

```
POST /Security/HelixSessionAuth.aspx HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 391

ClientIP=192.168.20.31
Url=%2Fflash%2F56553550%5Fhi%2Emp4
Log=SESSIONSTART%20%5B13%2FDec%2F2010%3A16%3A31%3A23%20%2B0000%5D%20%20flash%2F56553550%5Fhi%2Emp4%200%20192%2E168%2E20%2E31%203%20%5B13%2FDec%2F2010%3A16%3A31%3A23%20%2B0000%5D%200%200%200%20%5B0%20No%20Error%5D%20%5B0%20No%20Error%5D%20%5Brtmp%3A%2F%2Fhelix%2Epete%2Evideolibraryserver%2Ecom%2Fflash%2F56553550%5Fhi%2Emp4%5D%0A
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 13 Dec 2010 16:31:23 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 315

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Where abouts would they be in the above feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Form collection is the list of controls in the page that are passed to the action page via the POST method. Querystring is a GET, POST adds items to the Form collection. If you know the name of the control in the POST, you can access its value in the action page using:

```
Request.Form("myControl")
```

In .Net web forms, this is a little more complicated because .Net injects a specialized ClientID to preserve the ID of the actual control in the code behind.

The server collection is a collection of common server variables identifying information about the client, server, connection, browser, etc. A full list can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The link in this answer is broken :(

Comment: @ArminderDahul: Fixed with an msdn link that shouldn't deprecate anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark for this is a bit of a sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut, I'd suggest starting with the [MSDN documentation for HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h55b6cak%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). This should help you understand what the Form and Server collections are and what they represent, then you'll know what you are looking for in the actual data packet.

Comment: @Joel Etherton : It wasn't the best analogy but I couldn't think of a better one ;) It may have been a sledgehammer in itself. Someone sniffing packets relating to a URL such as '/Security/HelixSessionAuth.aspx' and looking for where data is passed always leaves me a little concerned so I resort to advice rather than answers.

Comment: It also depends on the nut in question, the metaphorical problem or the one attached to the keyboard ;)

Comment: @Lazarus: I'd say if he's working in .Net and doesn't have a grasp of these 2 concepts, a little packet sniffing is the least of his worries. :) I +1 you for the link though for going back to basics.

Comment: haha yeah developer with +4 years experience guys guess I just never REALLY understood these things till I asked...

Answer (score 1):

First about your tool. `WireShark` is a low level packet analysis tool which you don't need for learning HTTP concepts. Instead use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

**ServerVariables:**

This is an old object from asp classic. Now there are many aliases for their objects. For example `Request.UserHostAddress` is an alias for `Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")`.
Also `Headers`, `Cookies`, `Session` objects, ... are available from this object. This object is there more of backward compatibility.

**Form Variables:**

All controls in ASP.NET are tracked with an ID by ASP.NET and their state is hold within `ViewState` hidden field. view state, is the technique used by an ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to the state of a Web Form across `PostBacks`.
So, on every `PostBack` (form post, i.e click a button) ASP.NET at server side would repopulate form object and its children (controls inside the form) from post data. That's we call form collection.